# Variables in scope during for loop iteration statement in C++

Tags: c++, scope, language-lawyer, specifications

According to my understanding of the C++ specification (according to the draft standard online), a for-loop can be rewritten in terms of a while-loop and a block for initialization.  According to my understanding, the iteration statement of the for-loop occurs in the same scope as the body, so it should be able to use variables declared in the body of the for-loop.  Both gcc and clang reject the following (contrived) code, which is a simplification of my real code.

I can obviously fix the code by declaring j outside of the loop, but why is j out of scope below?

```
int main() 
{
    for(int i=0; i<10; i=j) int j=i+1;

    // // I must misunderstand the standard because I thought the above loop is 
    // // equivalent to the commented code below where j is clearly in scope.
    // {
    //     int i=0;
    //     while(i<10) {
    //         int j=i+1;
    //         i=j;
    //     }
    // }

    return 0;
 }
```

According to clang (and gcc), this is invalid.

```
test.cpp:3:26: error: use of undeclared identifier 'j'
    for(int i=0; i<10; i=j) int j=i+1;
                         ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: You're declaring `j` **after** you use it in `i=j`... The while loop doesn't do that.

Comment: It IS invalid syntax, since `j` is not declared until inside `for` loop, although it is not used before first loop completes.

Comment: @nhahtdh, That's what I meant. The compiler hasn't seen the declaration yet. When it's *used* is irrelevant in that regard.

Comment: @chris: My comment is a tad bit later than you, so it notifies you. It's not directed at you, though.

Comment: @nhahtdh, Ah, I mistook it for pedantry on the word "used", which is true nonetheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i=j) int j=i+1;
```

would, if it were valid syntax, be the same as

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i=j) 
{
  int j=i+1;
}
```

the for loop is then accessing 'j' inside the `{}` scope which doesn't exist until the first loop is executed. C++ is a static language which depends on the compiler being able to resolve its variables at compile time but what you are doing is trying to make it resolve the variable during runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I agree that the code you have written is equivalent to the for-loop but the draft standard I consulted further rewrites your code to the while-loop I wrote above (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf, page 111).  In the while-loop version, the j is clearly in scope.

Comment: You answer is actually correct, I think.  I should have converted my code to {int i=0; while(i<10) { {int j=i+1;} i=j }, which makes it clear that j is out of scope for the iteration part of the expression.

Comment: @GManNickG Page 110, section 6.5 paragraph 2.  

"If the substatement in an iteration-statement is a single statement and not a compound-statement, it is as if it was rewritten
to be a compound-statement containing the original statement."

Comment: This answer makes it sound like the first snippet is not syntactically correct, though it is. However, as John commented on my reference answer, §6.5/2 states there is an implicit block scope around the iteration statement.

Comment: @GManNickG You are certainly right that my snippet is syntactically valid, but Anders' answer seemed the closest.  I did not perform the rewrite of the body before rewriting to the while-loop form.

Comment: @JohnJumper: Right, my only complaint is that he seemed to deduce it based off compiler errors rather than any normative text; the answer should include some reference to the grammar for such a question, but obviously it's in the comments now so it's all good.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, the expansion is as follows (§6.5.3/1). The for-loop statement:

```
for (init cond; expr) statement
```

is equivalent to:

```
{
    init
    while (cond)
    {
        statement
        expr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes.  I misunderstood the nature of the "statement".  Specifically, I must enclose it in a block according to 6.5 substatement 2.

Answer (score 0):

It is somehow obvious. I'll give you an example. Can you write something like this?

```
int main(){
int i = j * 10;
//Some other lines ...
int j = 2;
return 0;
}
```

Of course in the given code i and j are in the same scope, but before using j you have to declare it.
You have to consider other things too besides the scope.

Comment: The same is not happening in his code, in the expansion the loop expression is after the statement.

Comment: Alright, I fixed it. However, he has to consider other things besides the scope.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get error is because 'j' is declared/ initialized inside for loop. But in C++ compilers compile from left to right and top to bottom, so when compiler encounters that 'i' is getting asigned with a garbage value, it pops up an error.